# Song 'You all over me' by Taylor Swift missing lyrics ''Shouldn't [?], but I never do''

Tags: lyrics, taylor-swift

Taylor Swift's song *You all over me* has these lyrics:

> [Verse 1]
>
> Once the last drop of rain, has dried off 
>   the pavement
>
> Shouldn’t [?], but I never do

The lyrics are missing after 'shouldn't'. I can't properly hear the words.

Does anyone know what are the missing lyrics?

I've searched on every site for the lyrics but the same [?].... What does this [?] mean? Also, if anyone knows the missing words from the lyrics-finding sites.

[Link for the lyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/you-all-over-me-lyrics-taylor-swift.html).

Answer (score 2):

The missing lyrics...

> Shouldn't I find a stain, but I never do

I couldn't find a good enough source to support my answer except this [Youtube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2axeRgE-Ew)

Comment: can you give a source for that ?

Comment: +1 for the research! @Bebs This is only an opinion, but it seems that the singer hopes to find an impression left behind by the raindrop(s) once it has dried off. The next line in the lyrics might logically co-relate with that assumption: _The way the tires turn stones on old county roads // You leave it muddy underneath, reminds me of you_

Answer (score 0):

There's no official lyrics yet because it is an unreleased song. I downloaded the song from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2axeRgE-Ew) and put it in Ableton. I also slowed down the tempo and even slowed it down by lowering the pitch too. I put it on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9lih4cha4lwblMtQXV5Q2syN0E/view?usp=sharing) but it is in .wav format. It sounds like she says "Shouldn't I find a stain, but I never do" but it also sounds like she says something else. The only conclusion any of us can make will have to wait until we have an official source tells us. I also want to point out that the song  title is "You All Over Me" and she talks about a love. That lyric could mean she is looking for a lipstick stain but she never does and that's why she loves him.

Comment: So you confirm chuck's answer...?

Comment: It sounds similar to that but I can't confirm anything. It sounds like she says a couple different things.